# 15.10 Unity stuck after login, even as guest, background image permission denied despite 644

Tags: unity, 15.10, lightdm, login-screen, display-manager

Yesterday I ran the last Ubuntu security updates, and now my desktop does not open anymore. Only the purple login wallpaper is visible (my user wallpaper is different and does not appear) and I can move the mouse, nothing else, right-clicking does nothing.

In `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log` I can see `unity-greeter.vala:587: Error starting Upstart for indicators: failed to execute child process "upstart" (No such file or directory)` and `background.vala:159: Error loading background: Failed to open file '/home/nico/Pictures/Wallpapers/alfresco-org.jpg': Permission denied` despite the permissions of my wallpaper image being 644.

Guest session does not open either. My personal $HOME is encrypted and does not get decruypted befire the screen gets stuck, so at that point I have no `.Xauthority` nor `.profile` nor `.xsession-errors`. Unencrypting $HOME before logging in does not solve the problem either.

I tried many suggestions found here and on the Internet but nothing works. In particular:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ... could not open display
...
no attribute 'get_default_screen'
```

[image]
Running as root `setsid service lightdm restart` results in the same problem, with this error (I use fingerprint login in case that matters):

```
Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling
  terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address
  (polkit-error-quark, 0)
XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
     after 417 requests (417 known processes) with 1 events remaining.
```

Running `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` as my user fails with `Failed to connect to Mir`.

Nothing special in `Xorg.0.log`.
By the way, `sudo lspci|grep VGA` says `Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)`.

After that, as a test I installed `kubuntu-desktop` and enabled [sddm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Desktop_Display_Manager) as the default window manager, result: it displays a popup `the system is running in low graphics mode` then ask whether I want to reconfigure or continue, if I continue the Ubuntu usual splash screen keeps looping endlessly. No `/var/log/sddm.log` file get created.

How to fix this?

Comment: "/home/nico/Pictures/Wallpapers/alfresco-org.jpg': Permission denied" did you check the directories too? The permission denied is more likely to be caused by a directory not having execute permissions or not being owned by you.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Good idea! I gave uog+rx permissions to all folders that make the image path (including $HOME!) and rebooted but still the same `Permission denied` error and still stuck.

Comment: The update messed up the xserver. Best I can suggest is to re-install xorg. But ... that is not the most friendly action to do (ie. can make things worse since you start by deleting packages related to xorg). How about a re-install of the driver for the video card (just to be on the safe side for now)>

Comment: @Rinzwind: I use Intel Integrated so no special drivers are needed right? Should I reinstall [like this](https://www.computersnyou.com/4945/re-install-xorg-xserver-completely-ubuntu/)?

Comment: Those are for amd and nvidia for will work for intel. Like I said: the 1st part is removing packages... so things could get worse if you do that ;-)